# meteorjs app error when implementing meteor-accounts-ldap

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm attempting to implement this meteorjs plugin to allow for LDAP/AD authentication.  The plugin installed without error, but when attempting to login I receive the following error.

```
I20150927-17:39:23.412(0)? Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Match error: Unknown key in field username
I20150927-17:39:23.412(0)?     at packages/check/match.js:299:1
I20150927-17:39:23.412(0)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
I20150927-17:39:23.412(0)?     at checkSubtree (packages/check/match.js:290:1)
I20150927-17:39:23.412(0)?     at check (packages/check/match.js:32:1)
I20150927-17:39:23.412(0)?     at [object Object].Accounts.registerLoginHandler.check.user (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:144:1)
I20150927-17:39:23.413(0)?     at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:358:1
I20150927-17:39:23.413(0)?     at tryLoginMethod (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:161:1)
I20150927-17:39:23.413(0)?     at runLoginHandlers (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:355:1)
I20150927-17:39:23.413(0)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:409:1)
I20150927-17:39:23.413(0)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150927-17:39:23.417(0)? Sanitized and reported to the client as: Match failed [400]
```

After scouring google for the past couple of days I'm not sure what else to try.  I have verified that my bind credentials are working properly and I'm able to search the subtree so it isn't an ldap issue.

Package: https://github.com/tdamsma/meteor-accounts-ldap/

Comment: Can you post a link to the package?

Comment: See this pull request: https://github.com/tdamsma/meteor-accounts-ldap/pull/3 .  The maintainer has yet to merge this fix.  You could clone the repo that initiated the pull request and see if that fixes your issue

Comment: That worked, add this as an answer so I can give credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this pull request: [#3](http://github.com/tdamsma/meteor-accounts-ldap/pull/3) . The maintainer has yet to merge this fix. You could clone the repo that initiated the pull request and see if that fixes your issue.

The pull request basically renames the `password` field to something else to avoid a conflict with the `accounts-password` package.